# Using jQuery Mobile to update URL string & refresh .load

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using PhoneGap & jQuery mobile to build out a native app. Most of the app lives in the webview with the exception of the header, navigation & footer. I have a list of article links inside the webview as well as a pagination link. When a user clicks the article link the new page is loaded into the existing webview and that's exactly what I want but the pagination links give me a jquery mobile loading error.

Essentially what I would like to do is append the pagination url to the end of the current webview URL, for example:

- Current webview URL is: m.example.com/?mode=Native;
- User clicks the pagination link(href="2/") and the webview updates to: m.example.com/2/?mode=Native

The javascript looks like this:

```
// loads first page into webview    
var mobPage = 'http://m.example.com/?mode=Native';

$('#content').load(mobPage, function() {
    $('#content').fadeIn(500);
});

// to load additional pages into webview
$('#articles a, #paginate a').live('click', function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var nextPage = $(this).attr('href');
    var mobPage = nextPage+"?mode=Native";
    $('#content').load(mobPage);
});
```

What is the proper way to do this?